# How can I validate the experience in years.month format only, by default 0.00?

Tags: javascript

I have tried by using by splitting the experience and checking the value at first index of result and then need to validate that value also.
My code was like

```
experince = "2.02";
var exp = experince.split(".");
var exp_dec = parseInt(exp[1]);
if (exp_dec[0] == "0" || exp_dec[0] == "1"){
    //validation successful;
}
```

I want to check for experience in years.
if experience is 3 year 4 month then it should allow 3.04
if experience is 1 year then it should be like 3.00
it should not contain any type of variable like "years"
it should not validate 1.3, 1.7 or 1.15,can only validate 1.10 or 1.01 or 1.07

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/a5p5jgc7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression like this:

```
var experienceFormat = /\d+\.((0\d)|(1[01]))/;

var result = experienceFormat.test('2.02');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wcc5pmhe/